# Why would people worship a specific god when given choices?

Tags: gods

So, I'm working on a story where there are 7 gods, one high god and 6 low gods, and the high god dies leading the 6 others ones to squabble on who'll be in charge. Each god represents a concept and each, at the start, are worshipped equally with no religion being persecuted. Gods get stronger the more they are worshipped. This means that he who has the most worshippers wins.
So, the 6 who I've chosen are

The god of lies, deception, stories, eloquence, etc

The god of gambling, money, exploitation, risks

The god of freedom, anarchy, violence, etc

The god of dreams, sleep, ideals, thinking

The god of order, stagnation, law, etc

The god of war, honor, combat, competition, etc

Which would the people naturally gravitate towards to worship?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take a good read at our [help] to understand our scope. We cannot write your story for you, and this is what you are asking. We can only help with the rules of your world.

Comment: Sorry, I was mainly asking who people would be drawn towards to worship. Sorry if it seems like I was asking more than that

Comment: A fight between gods, as a general fantasy rule, goes poorly for everyone. But yes, SO is meant to answer things which have a distinct "right" answer. World building is only a little different...

Comment: Sorry. Its my first question (I'll try to do better next time).

Comment: How would you recommend rephrasing the question?

Comment: @NielIGuess try hitting the "edit" button below your post and changing it. Maybe, "why do people worship certain gods" or "how did new gods historically gain followers?"

Comment: Does this seem a bit better?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post. Also keep in mind that the gods of your world are characters within your world and any questions about their decisions and plans are more a matter of storyteller's discretion than building your world.

Comment: I fixed it (hopefully)

Comment: You should edit the title to agree with the body of the question. However you're asking us to tell you what people in your world think. If you want a shrine to the god of lies in every farmer's hovel, you can have that. Alternatively if you want the worship of the god of lies to be punishable by death and it's worshippers to do so in secrete under the cover of the new moon, then that's how it will be in your world. Questions where the answer is entirely at the discretion of the worldbuilder aren't a good fit for this site.

Comment: Instead of asking us to make decisions about your world for you. Try building the world you want, and when you run into a problem try to ask us how to resolve a specific problem you're encountering.

Comment: It's exactly like asking if the Argonipons prefer to make pancakes or cereals for breakfast : Without knowing anything about who the people are, it's impossible to answer, or in the case when you're creating the culture, any answer is possible and equally valid :).

Comment: Is it possible for me to kill this question?

Comment: @NielIGuess There should be  **Share   Edit   Close   Delete** at the bottom of the question. To kill the question click **Delete**.

Comment: @Daron It's a bit too late now :/ ; Once a question received answers, it's impossible to close, only edit to improve... Though you can't invalidate existing answers through edits x_x. @ NiellGuess Don't worry though, it's your first question, it's normal to receive several feedbacks and asking for improvements. Take what you can from this question, and next time you'll break a leg (not litterally, it hurts!)!

Comment: @NielIGuess By the way, we have a [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to test your questions before going fully public and answerable. If you're worried about how a question will be received, we'll be glad to help you!

Answer (score 2):

**Every god will have their own followers**

The interesting thing about polytheism is that each God has our own job.  So I find that when you have multiple gods you have to figure out which department you need to get in contact with.  If you are a farmer planting seeds for the next harvest, please pray to the fertility goddess, if you are a warrior in need of divine help to win a battle, please pray to the war God, if you are in need of safe passage across a dangerous water way, please offer your virgin sacrifice to the sea god by the next full moon, you see what I’m getting at?  So naturally every God is going to attract its own type of followers.  Authors praying to the story God, traders praying to the money God, scholars praying to the dream God, judges praying to the law God and soldiers praying to the war God.  And some might even double deal like lawyers with the gods of lies and law.  So each God will find followers whether it’s by missionary outreach (have you heard a word about the god of freedom?) or by natural patronage (our family is blessed by the god of dreams).  As for who would win when it comes to getting the most prayers, that is going to be dependent on the tactics of their followers.  The war god could win by declaring jihad on everyone else, the freedom god could cause riots and revolution, the money god could cause a business boom, the idea god could have inventors creating an industrial revolution, the law god could try and bring order to the chaos, or it could reach an equilibrium where no one wins, but no one looses either.  Each gif has their job and each one has its place.

Comment: As a note, "double dipping" seemed to be historically normal in polytheistic religions. Alexander the Great paid devotion to many gods. Romans thought other cultures' worship and gods were just as valid as theirs, but also frequently equated foreign gods with their own. Ditto for Hinduism...ish Worshiping a single god exclusively when there are many seems abnormal (unless it's a member of clergy).

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see is that you present the 100% honest interpretation of what the Gods represent, but their PR department would just represent the most favorable version of it. Here is the ordering by which I think most people would follow these gods, based on what I know of people, and the primary attribute that I think they would insist they represent:

God Of Law:
The god of order, stagnation, law, etc
They would insist that they represent the upholding of the status quo, when really they're the church of oppression.

### God of Glory

The god of war, honor, combat, competition, etc
No great mystery here. Survival of the fittest.

### God of Opportunity:

The god of gambling, money, exploitation, risks
While presenting themselves as the champions of the downtrodden, they would encourage people to take longshots and benefit from survivorship bias.

### God of History:

The god of lies, deception, stories, eloquence, etc
Their insistence that they represent the one true perspective on history is plagued by people who remember when they told the story differently.

### God of Philosophy:

The god of dreams, sleep, ideals, thinking
Purity in thought results in inadequacy of action.

### God of Freedom:

The god of freedom, anarchy, violence, etc
Why do we need Gods? Oh, yea, because everyone else has one.

Comment: why do you think the freedom god owuld be so low? Wouldn't they appeal to the workers?

Comment: Primarily because true freedom involves a lack of communal responsibility. The priests wouldn't want to be tied down to a church, so they'd have crap PR. It would wind up being the god of vagabonds and thieves.